ドラゴンに遍く死を与えるモノ。Adverbial 遍く
So someone explained to me the meaning:
遍く（あまねく）: all over, widely,...
and translated the sentence as below:

‎ドラゴンに遍く死を与えるモノ
The man who will give all dragons death

To my research 遍く is supposed to be the adverbial of the term 与える as in 死を与えるモノ. And has meaning about the widely spread everywhere [of something] not the same as すべて, here "all dragon" should be すべてのドラゴン
So I think it have the nuance like spread death to dragon or something, I would translate to "The man who will give death all around to dragons."
If I am wrong, please explains to me about it, thank you.

I will also clarify that 遍{あまね}く is 連用形 / Continuative form (whose subfunction for adjectives is adverbialization) of classical adjective 遍{あまね}し (whose modern form would be 遍{あまね}い if it survived into modern language).

遍く indeed adverbially modifies 与える, and its basic meaning is "comprehensively", "ubiquitously", "all over" or "unconditionally". But that does not mean "give all dragons death" is a bad translation; in many cases, it's better to translate Japanese adverbs into English adjectives (e.g., イチゴを少し食べた → "I ate a few strawberries").
However, 遍く is an elevated and grand word that almost never appears in everyday informal conversation. In this respect, there might be room to consider an expression that sounds more dramatic than simply saying "all dragons". Something like "bestows death ubiquitously upon dragons" might be considered.
